# What would be a decent practice to get unique id for each MACHINE

Tags: security, windows, desktop-application

I'm focusing my question on Windows OS, desktop applications.

What would be a decent way to get a unique identification for every machine?

obviously there many ways to do that, such as concatenating a hash from network card's MAC address, or hard drive serial number, or even generating my own GUI number on initial launch, and saving it on the hard-disk \ registry, reading it every time i need it, but would like to avoid "inventing the wheel" and go for a more robust and proven approach.

My target use-case is to query a webservice. I would like to save each machine's preferences to my database, and return it to them when they ask for it. (backing up their personal settings)

Comment: Why not just use a standard function to generate a GUID? It wont get more robust and proven than that, unless you have some special requirements.

Comment: Ask the user for their email address.

Comment: fixed the question that you all for your suggestions

Comment: @polisha989: Will the clients have individual username/password for accessing the service? In that case you can associate the settings with the username.

Comment: You should detail a bit more on what the "machine's preferences" would be - It sound a bit like you would actually be looking to store *user preferences* instead . Which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: @tofro, I'd say it's not always 1-1 relationship between software preferences and users. Even not always 1-N - it all really depends on requirements to the software (e.g. when software is managing manufacturing process, there's no specific user, but there can be a user role responsible to configure the software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use process similar to registration of an user in a mobile app or social network.

1. Client software checks, if it already has UID. If yes, problem solved, it can pass it to server to restore settings.
2. If client software does not have yet UID, it requests new UID from server ("sign up" process). Server can either return standard UUID or serial integer number, whatever you choose, based on other requirements.
3. Client software stores UID for future use and, sends it to server when necessary ("sign in"). Likely, you will need to secure this process to avoid other clients guessing or intercepting the UID.

This, of course, works only if storage of UID is reliable and can provide UID every time you need to fetch data from server. If, for example, HDD with UID storage dies and there's no backup, you have to generate new UID and all stored settings will be effectively lost for that client.

There are many ways to choose local storage for UID, depending on how long it should persist. If hardware change and OS change means that client is new and settings shall not be restored - just put it in a file or system registry. If you need to persist settings between hardware changes and OS reinstalls, it will be better if you link it to user account (associated user must own the preferences or have access to change them) and authenticate user of the software instead (in this case acting as secret storage will be the user himself, remembering his password, providing fingerprints, inserting hardware token into USB port or using one-time code authenticator in his smartphone).